# Iphone build not connecting to Mobile First Server after Migration to 7.1 from 6.1

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I migrated Worklight 6.1 project to Mobile First 7.1

In 6.1 all builds(Android, Iphone and Windows) working fine but in 7.1 Iphone build is not working.

I given connectOnStartup : true to check connection with server.

Whenever I am going to launch Iphone build its giving error "The sever was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later".

But for Android build is working smoothly. Observed migrated Iphone build not getting internet access(Slider images on landing page are not loading even though their path given as url) but device has full high speed internet access.

Below things taken care:

1. There is no internet problem
2. Both iphone and server reside in same wifi network
3. Tried with making Customize URL in iphone

Answer (score 0):

> I given connectOnStartup : true to check connection with server.

This is a deprecated API and you should stop using it... Instead use the WL.Client.connect API if you really need to connect to the server on startup...

As for the connectivity issue, I suggest that you will check for the following:

1. You say you're making a "customized URL". I suggest that you will confirm you're actually using the correct URL for your server
2. Verify that in wlclient.plist you indeed have the correct server settings
3. If you are testing on iOS 9 or above, make sure your server is TL2 1.2-ready and your iOS application is configured for ATS: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/09/mobilefirst-platform-support-for-ios-9/

Comment: Tried with WL.Client.connect API as well by making connectOnStartup : false. But still not working. As I said above in 6.1 Iphone build is working fine and in 7.1 migrated build not working. Customised URL and wlclient.plist details taken care. Am using IFIX  IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160801-2314.